# How do I update LibreOffice to next point release in 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, libreoffice

I want to update my LibreOffice (whole package). Is there a way to do it without uninstalling old and then installing new?

If there is no option for updating directly, how should I do it otherwise? I don't want to keep the old version.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install libreoffice`. That updates libreoffice package.

Comment: AFAIK the libre-office installer automatically removes the older version. From your question it's not clear if you want to **keep** the older version too. Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: @FilipSohajek I have done what you told me and restarted my computer. It maybe updated libreoffice package, but it definitely hasn't updated LibreOffice (since it's 4.2 again).

Comment: Saying "It maybe updated libreoffice" and "but it definitely hasn't updated LibreOffice" in the same phrase is giving me only but confusion.

Comment: Yeah @Lucio, I guess I was convinced in a (wrong) idea that there is some difference between the two at the time. :D

Comment: @MuhamedHuseinbašić no worries pal! We both learned a lot in these three years :-)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The PPA [mentioned by jbuch14](https://askubuntu.com/a/505389/22949) is bleeding edge and not for you if you just want the 4.3 LibreOffice release.

For that, use

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-4-3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

This leaves you stuck on 4.3 until you decide to switch in a new repo and repeat this process but it will ensure you get all the release quality 4.3 updates without risking loading in libreoffice alpha or beta code.

[See this page](https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) for what the latest ppa is.

Comment: It doesn't quite leave you on 4.3; if the version in another repository you have added (including the default repositories) moves past that from this repository, then that would become the source used. Hence if they forgot about this for a while and Ubuntu did a release of 4.4, they would get 4.4.

Answer (score 41):

To get the latest version of LibreOffice (the one not directly located in the Ubuntu Repositories) add the libre ofice PPA.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

This should upgrade you to the latest version of Libre Office available.
Do note that the 4.3 package is not **YET** added to the PPA.

Comment: It's probably a good idea to mention that the 4.3 packages aren't there just yet.

Comment: You mean that the 4.3 packages arent in the Repo yet? Huh, I actually wasn't aware of that. Either way, this is handy to do to always keep LibreOffice up to date.

Comment: @mikewhatever That explains that these commands (although executed successfully) didn't updated LibreOffice to 4.3 (it remained 4.2). Thanks however. P.S. Is this means that there is no way to update to 4.3 (stable) yet?

Comment: I would wait until the PPA is updated, but if you're impatient, you can download the .deb file from the libreoffice.org site and install it with Software Center.

Comment: This is a 'bleeding edge' repo. See my answer below for a stable libreoffice 4.3 repo.

Comment: Tell me, will the upgrade (4.3) packages not be automatically offered through the Ubuntu Software updater?

Comment: Wippy's comment - now it's above

Answer (score 8):

The preferred way is to use the PPA, as answered by Jbuch14 above. The 4.3 packages aren't there yet, but should be in short order. The maintainer will have probably fixed packaging errors, (if any) and worked out the dependencies, but...

If you can't wait, and feel brave and adventurous, remove the 4.2 version, get the `debs` from http://www.libreoffice.org/download/libreoffice-fresh/, and install them "directly".

Here is an example of how it's done:

- removing - `sudo apt-get purge libreoffice*`
- downloading - [LibreOffice_4.3.0_Linux_x86_deb.tar.gz](http://donate.libreoffice.org/home/dl/deb-x86/4.3.0/en-US/LibreOffice_4.3.0_Linux_x86_deb.tar.gz)
- right-click, select `Extract here` to extract
- installing - `cd LibreOffice_4.3.0_Linux_x86_deb/DEBS; sudo dpkg -i *.deb`

PS: You can choose the desired language [here](http://www.libreoffice.org/download/libreoffice-fresh/?type=deb-x86&version=4.3&lang=pick).

Comment: I have done this for years, and it works well. You may want to add instructions for how to download the help package as well, although in my experience the download page always offers both the relevant language pack and the help pack. The main package must be installed first, followed by the language pack (if not US English), followed by the help pack.

Answer (score 5):

I've been researching this for the last 2 hours. It seems that everyone just gives a small piece of the puzzle. I have Ubuntu 14.04 with LibreOffice already installed (version 4.2.8). I want to completely remove my old version of LibreOffice and update to the latest stable version. This will not be the latest stable as defined by Ubuntu. Otherwise you would just use Ubuntu Software Center. What I don't want is the bleeding edge version which is released for people who want to report bugs and help in the development process. I just want the latest version that works. So here are my COMPLETE steps. I welcome anyone to comment on how this process can be improved:

1. Open a terminal by the keys ctrl-alt T
2. Enter this sequence of commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge libreoffice* 
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

[image: LibreOfficeAbout.png]

This was my result.

Answer (score 4):

Those who, like me, do not want to update the whole system, can use Jbuch14 answer with one slight change

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libreoffice #<--- line that changed
```

I've just updated LibreOffice with this command and now I am on 4.4.0.3 (Ubuntu 14.04 x64).

Answer (score 3):

Everything is [here in the LibreOffice official documentation](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LibreOffice#Installing_a_newer_version_of_LibreOffice_than_available_via_Ubuntu_repositories)

I just updated LibreOffice 4.2 to 4.3 myself (Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS), following those instructions. Contrary to a lot of misleading information on the web, it is really totally simple and you do not have to remove anything or delete your customizations etc. 
So to upgrade 4.2 to 4.3 while keeping all your settings all you have to do is:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
```

Then check out the PPA for very latest version of LibreOffice at [here](https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ppa).

Following installation instructions is for 4.3

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-4-3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

Answer (score 1):

A portable version of LibreOffice 4.3.0.4 has been recently released for 32-bit and 64-bit systems. The packages are built by probono on Sourceforge using [AppImageKit](https://github.com/probonopd/AppImageKit). I've just uploaded LibreOffice 4.3 on my USB and it works flawlessly!

You can find LibreOffice 4.3.0.4 Portable here:

- [https://sourceforge.net/projects/portable](https://sourceforge.net/projects/portable/files/)

In order to run the office, just mark it as executable.

Answer (score 0):

The 4.4 stable branch is already available in Ubuntu, using it now in Ubuntu 14.04 x64

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-4-4
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I use

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
```

And then open the "updater" and I can see the some Libre update lists in the window. It's pretty easy to update Libreoffice 4 to 5